# processing data in one row per user with python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv, data-processing

I am collecting user data from csv files generated by Google Analytics custom reports and some user attributes have multiple values per users. My objective here is to get user data and place all relevant data pertaining to one user into one row.

Example:

```
users = [
  { id:1, name: 'user1'},
  { id:2, name: 'user2'},
  { id:3, name: 'user3'}
 ]

 products_purchased = [
  {id:1 , product_purchased: 'sardines'},
  {id:1, product_purchased: 'shoes'},
  {id:2 , product_purchased: 'fish'},
  {id:2, product_purchased: 'chicken'},
  {id:3 , product_purchased: 'eggs'},
  {id:3, product_purchased: 'chicken'},
]
```

I am trying to re-arrange the data for machine learning like so:

```
users = [
  { id:1, name: 'user1', product_purchased-1: 'sardines',
    product_purchased-2: 'shoes'},
  { id:2, name: 'user2', product_purchased-1:'fish',
    product_purchased-2: 'chicken' },
  { id:3, name: 'user3', product_purchased-1: 'eggs', 
    product_purchased-2: 'chicken'}
 ]
```

the following is my Python code:

```
import csv


processed = []
columns = ['id', 'username', 'country','city','region','event-1','event-2','event-3',
'event-4', 'event-5','event-6','event-7','event-8','event-9','event-10','product-1',
'product-2','product-3','product-4','product-5','product-6','product-7','product-8',
'product-9','product-10','page-1','page-2','page-3','page-4','page-5','Sessions with Event',
'Total Events','Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Conversion Rate)',
'Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Completions)']
i = 0
#columns =[] 'ID', 'WP Username' , country, city, region, event action 1 (10 actions), products (multiple), 'Sessions with Event',Total Events, Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Conversion Rate),
# Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Completions)

# Completed the main dimentions of the GA data
# getting details per unique user
with open('users.csv') as users_data:
    user_dict = csv.DictReader(users_data)
    users = list(user_dict)

    for user in users:
        processed.append({
            'id': user['ID'],
            'username': user['WordPress_Username'],
            'country':user['Country'],
            'city':user['City'],
            'region':user['Region']
        })

with open('events.csv') as events_data:
    events_dict = csv.DictReader(events_data)
    events = list(events_dict)

    for p in processed:
        for event in events:
            i += 1
            if p['id'] == event['ID']:
                p['event-' + str(i)] = event['Event Action']
            else:
                i = 0

with open('products.csv') as products_data:
    products_dict = csv.DictReader(products_data)
    products = list(products_dict)

    for p in processed:
        for product in products:
            i += 1
            if p['id'] == product['ID']:
                p['product-' + str(i)] = product['Product ID']
            else:
                i = 0

with open('pages.csv') as page_visited:
    pages_dict = csv.DictReader(page_visited)
    pages = list(pages_dict)

    for p in processed:
        for page in pages:
            i +=1
            if p['id'] == page['ID']:
                 p['page-' + str(i)] = page['Page']
            else:
                i = 0


for p in processed:
    for user in users:
        p['Sessions with Event'] = user['Sessions with Event']
        p['Total Events'] = user['Total Events']
        p['Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Conversion Rate)'] = user['Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Conversion Rate)']
        p['Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Completions)'] = user[ 'Adding a product on to the cart (Goal 4 Completions)']
    for event in events:
        if p['id'] == event['ID']:
            p['Sessions'] = event['Sessions']
    for page in pages:
        if p['id'] == page['ID']:
            p['id'] = page['Pages / Session']



try:
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as data:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(data, fieldnames=columns)
        writer.writeheader()
    for p in processed:
        writer.writerow(p)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

I would like to know what is wrong with my code or an alternative that can also accomplish what I am looking for. I have tried Google Data Studio before and it seems there options in GA that allows me to do that.

I intend to later on use scikit learn clustering on the data which is why I am formatting the data in  order to create a pandas data frame.

Out of curiousity: Can pivot tables be used to create dataframes? and would that format work for scikit learn?

UPDATE: I fixed the bracket issue on the event['Sessions'] line. BUt now I get the following error:

```
  File "data_processing.py", line 87, in <module>
    writer.writerow(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: A closing bracket is needed in line 75: [event['Sessions']]

Comment: @xbello Thank you, but now I am receiving another error , I still cant seem to find what is wrong? the python code I have is valid

Comment: One tip I always use with syntax errors like this: Always check the line above

Comment: In the case of your second error, check the indentation. The `with open()` context manager is dependent on indetation to know how long to keep the file open

Answer (score 0):

I would like to Thank everyone who responded to my question ! a big thanks to @xbello and @G.Anderson. As they have both pointed out, the problem was a matter of me having a bracket in line 75  ("[event['Sessions']") and didnt indent proper on the final with open statement.